# Binding to a scroll event inside nested views

Tags: angularjs, scroll, ng-view

I need to track if top 300 pixels my subview have scrolled out of the visible area, however I cannot bind to a scroll event of this view (but can bind to 'resize'!)

Location: index.html -> global layout -> content area -> subview (this one)

```
    .state('my', {
        url: '/my',
        views: {
            '': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/views/layout.html'
                },
            'content': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/views/content.html' <-- inside this view we have ng-view, with my subtemplate loaded into it.
                }
            },
```

Important: this is not a windowed / limited height view. It has a header, but no footer, i.e. can be any length depending on the contents length.

Please help!
D.

**Update**

I've found the following workaround. Please let me know how ugly is that from AngularJS point of view?

```
var el = angular.element(document.getElementById('top'));

    $scope.$watch(function () {
        $timeout(function () {
            var top = el[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;
            if (top < -160) {
                // Doing this
            } else {
                // Doing that
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: any special reason why you can' t bind a scroll event ?

Comment: @topheman
The only suspicion is this amount of nested views + fact of using material design.

Btw. I have an update - found a workaround: will update the ticket above.